# PHP convert uppercase words to lowercase, but keep ucfirst on lowercase words

Tags: php, string

**An example:**

```
THIS IS A Sentence that should be TAKEN Care of
```

**The output should be:**

```
This is a Sentence that should be taken Care of
```

**Rules**

- Convert UPPERCASE words to lowercase
- Keep the lowercase words with an uppercase first character intact
- Set the first character in the sentence to uppercase.

**Code**

```
$string = ucfirst(strtolower($string));
```

**Fails**

It fails because the ucfirst words are not being kept.

```
This is a sentence that should be taken care of
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test each word for those rules:

```
$str = 'THIS IS A Sentence that should be TAKEN Care of';
$words = explode(' ', $str);
foreach($words as $k => $word){
    if(strtoupper($word) === $word || // first rule
           ucfirst($word) !== $word){ // second rule 
        $words[$k] = strtolower($word);
    }
}
$sentence = ucfirst(implode(' ', $words)); // third rule
```

Output:

> This is a Sentence that should be taken Care of

---

A little bit of explanation:
Since you have overlapping rules, you need to individually compare them, so...

- Break down the sentence into separate words and check each of them based on the rules;
- If the word is UPPERCASE, turn it into lowercase; *(THIS, IS, A, TAKEN)*
- If the word is ucfirst, leave it alone; *(Sentence, Care)*
- If the word is NOT ucfirst, turn it into lowercase, *(that, should, be, of)*

Comment: I think you should try to put it in one row. You could move the comments above the lines. So far I like this and @iainn solutions.

Comment: I noticed that in my case I needed to use mb_strtoupper and mb_strtolower to handle åäö characters in a mysql database.

Comment: Great, I'm glad it worked. It's the same logic, but with a function that can handle your current case ;) - your comment will help others that need it too.

Answer (score 2):

You can break the sentence down into individual words, then apply a formatting function to each of them:

```
$sentence = 'THIS IS A Sentence that should be TAKEN Care of';

$words = array_map(function ($word) {
    // If the word only has its first letter capitalised, leave it alone
    if ($word === ucfirst(strtolower($word)) && $word != strtoupper($word)) {
        return $word;
    }

    // Otherwise set to all lower case
    return strtolower($word);
}, explode(' ', $sentence));

// Re-combine the sentence, and capitalise the first character
echo ucfirst(implode(' ', $words));
```

See https://eval.in/936462

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "THIS IS A Sentence that should be TAKEN Care of";
$str_array = explode(" ", $str);
  foreach ($str_array as $testcase =>$str1) {
    //Check the first word
    if ($testcase ==0 && ctype_upper($str1)) {
      echo ucfirst(strtolower($str1))." ";
    }
    //Convert every other upercase to lowercase
    elseif( ctype_upper($str1)) {
      echo strtolower($str1)." ";
    }
    //Do nothing with lowercase
    else {
      echo $str1." ";
    }
  }
```

**Output:**

---

This is a Sentence that should be taken Care of

Answer (score 1):

I find `preg_replace_callback()` to be a direct tool for this task.  Create a pattern that will capture the two required strings:

1. The leading word
2. Any non-leading, ALL-CAPS word

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/2sKAM))

```
echo preg_replace_callback(
         '~(^\pL+\b)|(\b\p{Lu}+\b)~u',
         function($m) {
             return $m[1]
                 ? mb_convert_case($m[1], MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8')
                 : mb_strtolower($m[2], 'UTF-8');
         },
         'THIS IS A Sentence that should be TAKEN Care of'
     );
// This is a Sentence that should be taken Care of
```

I did not test this with multibyte input strings, but I have tried to build it with multibyte characters in mind.

The custom function works like this:

- There will always be either two or three elements in `$m`. If the first capture group matches the first word of the string, then there will be no `$m[2]`. When a non-first word is matched, then `$m[2]` will be populated and `$m[1]` will be an empty string.  There is a modern flag that can be used to force that empty string to be `null`, but it is not advantageous in this case.
- `\pL+` means one or more of any letter (single or multi-byte)
- `\p{Lu}+` means one or more uppercase letters
- `\b` is a word boundary.  It is a zero-width character -- it doesn't match a character, it checks that the two consecutive characters change from a word to a non-word or vice versa.
- My answer makes just 3 matches/replacement on the sample input string.

Comment: It seems to work as expected. Nice that you are taking multibyte characters into account as well.

Answer (score -2):

```
$string='THIS IS A Sentence that should be TAKEN Care of';
$arr=explode(" ", $string);
foreach($arr as $v)
{
    $v = ucfirst(strtolower($v));
    $stry = $stry . ' ' . $v;
}
echo $stry;
```

Comment: 1: might not even run (`$stry` is not defined, so `type 8 -- Undefined variable: stry` - but can be _ignored_); 2: doesn't produce the expected output; 3: answer not formatted.